# adding table to an existing query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table simsu_subs that has fields user_id and expiry date.
That same field name, user_id is used in another table, mt_links.

I have this query working perfectly:

```
SELECT link_published,
    CASE link_published WHEN 1 THEN 'Published' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Published/no',
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,
    accreditations,
    title_descriptor,
    phone_number,
    display_email,
    u.website,
    avatar,
    logo,
    disclaimer,
    signature_ie_john_doe,
    MAX(IF(lv.cf_id =24, lv.`value`, '')) AS `UploadGraphic`,
    MAX(IF(lv.cf_id =36, lv.`value`, '')) AS `Color`,
    MAX(IF(lv.cf_id =37, lv.`value`, '')) AS `BodyCopy`,
    MAX(IF(lv.cf_id =39, lv.`value`, '')) AS `Salutation`,
    l.link_name,
    MAX(IF(lv.cf_id =38, lv.`value`, '')) AS `Magazine`,
    address,
    MAX(IF(lv.cf_id =35, lv.`value`, '')) AS `Address 2`,
    city,
    state,
    postcode FROM cwpc_jsn_users u 
    INNER JOIN cwpc_mt_links l ON u.`id` = l.`user_id`
    INNER JOIN cwpc_mt_cfvalues lv ON l.link_id = lv.link_id
GROUP BY u.firstname, l.link_name
```

This is the query I want to add:

```
SELECT b.expiry_date
FROM cwpc_simsu_subs b
JOIN cwpc_mt_links c
ON b.user_id = c.user_id
```

I would like to add expiry_date to this query, joined by user_id. I've tried to alias the field and inner join in more ways than I care to count. I just can't get it to work. I'm thinking the line

> INNER JOIN cwpc_mt_links l ON u.`id` = l.`user_id`

has something to do with it? Not completely sure though.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias `l` is already being used, so that might be your problem.  I would expect your `FROM` clause to look like:

```
FROM cwpc_jsn_users u 
     INNER JOIN cwpc_mt_links l ON u.`id` = l.`user_id`
     INNER JOIN cwpc_mt_cfvalues lv ON l.link_id = lv.link_id 
     INNER JOIN cwpc_simsu_subs b ON b.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: I didn't think to reuse u.id instead of giving it another alias. Stupid mistake, really. Thank you for pointing that out!!!